# Prevent onChange of a textbox onClick of a button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox and a button. I have binded onchange event with textbox and click event on button. I want to avoid textbox's onchange event when user clicks on a button.

```
<asp:textbox id="txt1" runat="server"/>
<asp:button id="btn1" runat="server" text="Submit"/>
```

Jquery

```
$("txt1").bind("change", function(){
// do some work;
});


$("btn1").bind("click", function(){
//avoid on change event of textbox
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#btn1").bind("click", function(){
   $('#txt1').unbind('change');
});
```

Comment: nope.   the onchange even fires before the click event.   however `$("#btn1").bind("mousedown")`  will happen first